# How to use async task to control a view pager

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I am trying to create an auto image slider using a view pager following some tutorials. I got everything working, but then I see

`Choreographer: Skipped 1 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` and googled the error.`

You see, in my code, I have a timer and a handler that just delay the code for 3 seconds and then slides the view pager to the next image. I confirmed with a friend and after hours of searching, there was nothing else that was doing too much work on the main thread.

So searching on stack overflow about the problem, I see that a lot of developers suggested using AsyncTask to do some stuff in background and then update, which might actually be a perfect solution here. But then I realised that I know nothing about AsyncTask. I went to the android developers reference and saw some tutorials, but I was unable to find something that'll fit into my solution.

I saw a lot of tutorials about image downloading, but they are by far, not what I'm concerned with. I am only concerned with controlling the view pager to move to the next slide.

Here is the part where I control my view pager to slide:

```
// Auto start of viewpager
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        };
        Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 3000, 3000);
```

How do I incorporate this code into an AsyncTask?

For reference, I used [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=autoimageslider+demonuts&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN855IN855&oq=autoimageslider+demonuts&aqs=chrome..69i57.6349j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) tutorial.

Comment: you can solve this problem with RunOnUiThread

Comment: Why don't you use third party library instead of using Handler and Runnable for image sliding..

Comment: @Abhishek, I am a beginner, and I wouldn't know if there is a good library with minimum configuration/integration that'd run without causing issues. Please do suggest if you have anything in mind.

Comment: @SowingFiber Have a look on this https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider and https://github.com/saeedsh92/Banner-Slider that doesn't require a lot of code. You can use one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runnable is a seprate worker thread, it has no interaction with main thread. When you are handling ui  elements, use runOnUiThread. example.

```
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        });
```

or

```
runOnUiThread(){
 mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does work, however only once at the start of the app. My original code ran it multiple times. I removed the Timer, because, it was the one probably creating the `Choreographer` message.

Comment: Timer also require runOnUiThread, if it is thandling UI events so please put  handler.post(Update); in runOnUiThread.

Comment: I have updated my code like [this](https://gist.github.com/SowingFiber/a2ea1756feb5fe009590c6a326919427) and I still get the `Choreographer` logs in my messages. Is it because of the timer? Is there a better solution for repeating code after a delay than the timer?

Comment: try putting  handler.post(Update); in runuitheard like. runOnUiThread(){
   handler.post(Update);
}    give this a try

Comment: Still, the issue remains. Is there any other way to delay and repeat code like the timer? Maybe that could work? Any suggestions?

Comment: there are no error logs, there is just a message that comes in the logcat repeatedly

`I/Choreographer: Skipped 1 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find two methods on how can one run a code on the main/UI thread on android:

1. runOnUIThread Activity’s method

```java
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
     public void run() {
          // UI code goes here
     }
});
```

2. Handler

```java
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
          // UI code goes here
     }
});
```

[source](https://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2014/04/06/run-code-on-mainui-thread-on-android/#.XWeAHOgzZ6s)

Comment: I have updated my code like [this](https://gist.github.com/SowingFiber/a2ea1756feb5fe009590c6a326919427) and I still get the `Choreographer` logs in my messages. Is it because of the timer? Is there a better solution for repeating code after a delay than the timer?